# C# Web Browser with click and highlight of Frame/iFrame elements

Tags: c#, web-scraping

Iam looking for a browser control where users can preview frame/iframe in web page and then highlight elements of it and once highlighted, I can get the div or id of the element selected.

Is there any way we can do it ?

Answer (score 1):

I have got the answer...!
Try this code to get iframes and frames residing in the webpage and add document handlers for the same.
Its just simple, we need to add document handlers for each frame/iframe.

```
    private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted_1(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (this.webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)

            return;
        else
        {

            HtmlDocument _document = webBrowser1.Document;
            _document.MouseOver += new HtmlElementEventHandler(document_MouseOver);
            _document.MouseLeave += new HtmlElementEventHandler(document_MouseLeave);
            mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event iEvent;
            IHTMLDocument2 currentDoc = (IHTMLDocument2)webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
            iEvent = (mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event)currentDoc;
            iEvent.onclick += new mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents2_onclickEventHandler(clickDocumentHandler);

            if (currentDoc.frames.length > 0)
            {
                FramesCollection FrameList = currentDoc.frames;

                for (int i = 0; i < FrameList.length; i++)
                {
                    object id = (object)i;

                    IHTMLWindow2 frameWindow = (IHTMLWindow2)FrameList.item(ref id);
                    IHTMLDocument2 frameDocument = (IHTMLDocument2)frameWindow.document;
                    iEvent = (mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents2_Event)frameDocument;
                    iEvent.onclick += new mshtml.HTMLDocumentEvents2_onclickEventHandler(clickDocumentHandler);



                }

            }




        }
    }


    private bool clickDocumentHandler(IHTMLEventObj pEvtObj)
    {
        IHTMLElement element = (mshtml.IHTMLElement)pEvtObj.srcElement;
        label2.Text = element.id;
        pEvtObj.cancelBubble = true;
        pEvtObj.returnValue = false; 
        return false;
    }

    private bool clickElementHandler(IHTMLEventObj pEvtObj)
    {
        IHTMLElement element = (mshtml.IHTMLElement)pEvtObj.srcElement;
        label1.Text = element.id;
        pEvtObj.cancelBubble = true;
        pEvtObj.returnValue = false;
        return false;
    }

    private void document_MouseOver(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlElement element = e.FromElement;
        mshtml.HTMLElementEvents2_Event iEvent;
        iEvent = element.DomElement as mshtml.HTMLElementEvents2_Event;
        if (iEvent == null)
            return;
        iEvent.onclick += new mshtml.HTMLElementEvents2_onclickEventHandler(clickElementHandler);
    }

    private void document_MouseLeave(object sender, HtmlElementEventArgs e)
    {
        HtmlElement element = e.FromElement;
        mshtml.HTMLElementEvents2_Event iEvent;
        iEvent = element.DomElement as mshtml.HTMLElementEvents2_Event;
        if (iEvent == null)
            return;
        iEvent.onclick -= new mshtml.HTMLElementEvents2_onclickEventHandler(clickElementHandler);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

**In order to get rid of the Cross Frame Issue 
We have to change one line of code while attaching the event handler to frame document.**

```
    IHTMLDocument2 frameDocument = (IHTMLDocument2) CrossFrame.GetDocumentFromWindow  (frameWindow);
```

**include Interop.SHDocVw.dll and Add the below class:**

```
 public class CrossFrame
 {
    // Returns null in case of failure.
    public static IHTMLDocument2 GetDocumentFromWindow(IHTMLWindow2 htmlWindow)
    {
        if (htmlWindow == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        // First try the usual way to get the document.
        try
        {
            IHTMLDocument2 doc = htmlWindow.document;
            return doc;
        }
        catch (COMException comEx)
        {
            // I think COMException won't be ever fired but just to be sure ...
            if (comEx.ErrorCode != E_ACCESSDENIED)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        catch (System.UnauthorizedAccessException)
        {
        }
        catch
        {
            // Any other error.
            return null;
        }

        // At this point the error was E_ACCESSDENIED because the frame contains a document from another domain.
        // IE tries to prevent a cross frame scripting security issue.
        try
        {
            // Convert IHTMLWindow2 to IWebBrowser2 using IServiceProvider.
            IServiceProvider sp = (IServiceProvider)htmlWindow;

            // Use IServiceProvider.QueryService to get IWebBrowser2 object.
            Object brws = null;
            sp.QueryService(ref IID_IWebBrowserApp, ref IID_IWebBrowser2, out brws);

            // Get the document from IWebBrowser2.
            SHDocVw.IWebBrowser2 browser = (SHDocVw.IWebBrowser2)(brws);

            return (IHTMLDocument2)browser.Document;
        }
        catch
        {
        }

        return null;
    }

    private const int E_ACCESSDENIED = unchecked((int)0x80070005L);
    private static Guid IID_IWebBrowserApp = new Guid("0002DF05-0000-0000-C000-000000000046");
    private static Guid IID_IWebBrowser2 = new Guid("D30C1661-CDAF-11D0-8A3E-00C04FC9E26E");
}

// This is the COM IServiceProvider interface, not System.IServiceProvider .Net interface!
[ComImport(), ComVisible(true), Guid("6D5140C1-7436-11CE-8034-00AA006009FA"),
InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIUnknown)]
public interface IServiceProvider
{
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    [PreserveSig]
    int QueryService(ref Guid guidService, ref Guid riid, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out object ppvObject);
}
```

Comment: I am also looking to this. What I want is to attach event handlers to elements inside iframes. But I getting access denied exception. I have try with your method but I don't have any idea about how to implement `QueryService` method inside my class. Can you please put that code or give a hint to figure it out. thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have got another way of doing...

```
          using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

**Declare a delegate**

```
          public delegate void DOMEvent(IHTMLEventObj e);

  private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted_1(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (this.webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)

            return;
        else
        {

            HTMLDocument htmlDoc = (HTMLDocument)this.webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
            DispHTMLDocument doc = (DispHTMLDocument)htmlDoc;

            DOMEventHandler onmousedownhandler = new DOMEventHandler(doc);
            onmousedownhandler.Handler += new DOMEvent(Mouse_Down);
            doc.onmousedown = onmousedownhandler;

            if (htmlDoc.frames.length > 0)
            {
                FramesCollection FrameList = htmlDoc.frames;

                for (int i = 0; i < FrameList.length; i++)
                {
                    object id = (object)i;

                    IHTMLWindow2 frameWindow = (IHTMLWindow2)FrameList.item(ref id);
                    HTMLDocument frameDoc = (HTMLDocument)frameWindow.document;
                    DispHTMLDocument frameDispDoc = (DispHTMLDocument)frameDoc;
                    DOMEventHandler onmousedownhand = new DOMEventHandler(frameDispDoc);
                    onmousedownhand.Handler += new DOMEvent(Mouse_Down);
                    frameDispDoc.onmousedown = onmousedownhand;

                }
            }

        }
    }


        public class DOMEventHandler
        {
        public DOMEvent Handler;
        DispHTMLDocument Document;
        public DOMEventHandler(DispHTMLDocument doc)
        {

            this.Document = doc;

        }
        [DispId(0)]

        public void Call()
        {
            Handler(Document.parentWindow.@event);
        }
    }

       public void Mouse_Down(IHTMLEventObj e)
        {
        IHTMLElement element = (mshtml.IHTMLElement)e.srcElement;
        label1.Text = element.id;

         }
```