# Error getting iFrame width and height in OnDocumentComplete

Tags: c++, bho, windows-8.1, internet-explorer-11

I have an IE Browser Helper Object (BHO) (written in C++) which records the height and width of iFrame(s) and the Main page when it receives a document complete notification (OnDocumentComplete). This code has been running fine up until now (all older Windows and IE versions) but has stopped working in IE11 (desktop) on Windows 8.1 for iFrames. Getting the width and height for the Main page still works.

I am using the get_Height and get_Width functions from the IWebBrowser2 interface. A call to these functions now return an error, 0x80004005 (Unspecified error) and the height and width returned back is 0.

Has anyone encountered this issue? It sounds like this could be a bug in IE11. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Web Browser with click and highlight of Frame/iFrame elements](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11650895/c-sharp-web-browser-with-click-and-highlight-of-frame-iframe-elements)

Answer (score 0):

I've observed that IE9+ (including IE11) seems to fire onload= type DOM events "early," before the entire DOM is loaded.  In particular in my case where I've got the browser DOM loading an SVG document.  Webpages having `<object>` tags in them might be another risky area.  My work around was to catch the onload= event, then wait another 0.75 seconds for the DOM to settle down.  An imperfect, crazy hack, but it seemed to help.